# Azure v1 ServiceBusTrigger function not picking up messages

Tags: c#, azure, azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-queues

I have a couple Azure functions pushing messages into the ServiceBus, configured like so:

```
[FunctionName("UpsertEntity")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "v1/Entity/Upsert")]HttpRequestMessage req, 
    [ServiceBus("archive", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ArchiveQueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<ArchiveMessage> archiveAsyncCollector,
    [ServiceBus("crm", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "CRMQueueConnectionString")] IAsyncCollector<BrokeredMessage> crmAsyncCollector, 
    TraceWriter log)

...

await archiveAsyncCollector.AddAsync(new ArchiveMessage(ConfigKeys.UpsertEntityMessageLabel, DateTime.UtcNow) { Content = jsonContent });
await crmAsyncCollector.AddAsync(new BrokeredMessage(entity) { Label = ConfigKeys.UpsertEntityMessageLabel });
```

I can see the messages do get posted to the ServiceBus no problem.
Then I have two functions that should process them, yet they never seem to trigger. The function are defined as:

```
[FunctionName("ProcessMessage")]
public static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("crm", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "CRMQueueConnectionString")]BrokeredMessage message, TraceWriter log)

[FunctionName("ArchiveMessage")]
public async static void Run([ServiceBusTrigger("archive", AccessRights.Manage, Connection = "ArchiveQueueConnectionString")] Messages.ArchiveMessage archiveMessage,
    //[Table("MessageArchive")] CloudTable outputTable, TraceWriter log)
    TraceWriter log)
```

Neither seems to ever get triggered, logs are empty as well, not even any exceptions.

I've double checked the connection string is valid.

One thing that potentially comes to mind is whether it's not some assembly mismatch, I'm targeting functions v1 and using the `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus` package `v2.2.0`.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So for anybody as dumb as me:

Double check your whitelist in `host.json` and make sure all your functions are listed there.